# Using Google Maps Distance Matrix API on Excel- where did I go wrong?

Tags: vba, excel, google-maps

I'm trying to use baelaelael's code from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35700537/using-google-maps-distance-matrix-api-on-excel-with-less-api-calls) on GMDMA in Excel on Windows 10 and I am running into errors I can't understand.

I need to populate a pretty huge database (254x30) for my thesis with distances, and I am trying to avoid hand-Googling everything- so if I can call 2000 or so each day for a couple days with the `=GetDistance` function that should do the trick.

I am getting the function to return an error (-1) in the sheet, so it seems my first foray into VBA is at least making it into the Excel sheet...

I tried adding my API key because I thought that might be the issue.

Here's the code:

```
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String)

    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String

    firstVal = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
    secondVal = "+&destinations="
    lastVal = "+&mode=car&language=en&sensor=false&key=###################################"

    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    URL = firstVal & Replace(start, " ", "+") & secondVal & Replace(dest, " ", "+") & lastVal

    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")

    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """distance"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl

    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = """value"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False

    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)

    tmpVal = Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", Application.International(xlListSeparator))

    GetDistance = CDbl(tmpVal)

    Exit Function

ErrorHandl:

    GetDistance = -1

End Function
```

And then I'm calling the function in the sheet with:

```
=GetDistance(B12,T3)
```

But I figured that might be wrong so I tried:

```
=GetDistance($P$13,T4)
```

For another set of cells following the syntax the original code user posted and that didn't work either. Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the format of B12 and T3? Can you give an example?

Comment: i tried this http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=paris+&destinations=london&mode=car&language=en&sensor=false&key=#########   .... it works without a key a few times a day and returns json data, so the problem is not the key

Comment: i also tried your code by calling it from a vba sub and it worked.  the code accepts two strings (city names are ok) .... also tried in a cell and it worked ... did you put city names in B12 and T3 ?  the value returned is a distance in meters.

Comment: i should have asked you this first:  **what errors are you getting?**

Comment: Both cells (ie B12 and T3) are either  (both) addresses or  (both) decimal degree coordinates. I also got their sample code to work. The code has an error handling line that returns -1 to the excel sheet for an error, so its not clear what is going wrong.

Comment: looks like the 'string' data type is the problem...incompatible with decimal degrees maybe. feeding in cells like this: 31.832559, -94.897930

Comment: apparently its not the string type, its returning a variable undefined error for "objHTTP ="

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Built the URL by hand following the program, and it returned an ssl error. Added an 's' to the URL line of code and its returning the correct values in meters. Corrected code reads as follows:

```
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String)
Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String
firstVal = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
secondVal = "+&destinations="
lastVal = "+&mode=car&language=en&sensor=false&key=####################################################################"
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = firstVal & Replace(start, " ", "+") & secondVal & Replace(dest, " ", "+") & lastVal
objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send ("")
If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """distance"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = """value"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
tmpVal = Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
GetDistance = CDbl(tmpVal)
Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
GetDistance = -1
End Function
```

The code takes addresses, decimal degrees, whatever. Hope this is useful for someone. You have to activate the google distance matrix API first and get a key and insert that into the code where I put the ############s. Cheers.